# XAMPPLITE / Web Application - auto install

Tags: installation, xampp

Would like to hear comments from you if its possible to accomplish this with a single mouse click on a bat/exe file -> if its possible to accomplish the following two steps into one:

1: Install xampplite

2: Paste a web application into the htdocs folder. The web application has a file install.php. The install.php file will install the database and prepare the web application for further use.

Thanx,

Answer (score 0):

Why should that not be possible? But installing xmapp on a computer with the generall installer asks you where you want to have the files.

An other idea could be by using the zip file. AFAIK you can unzip files from cmd (by invoking the zip function) to a destination you set, copy the webapplication to the htdocs folder, starting up apache and call an URL to your installer script.